# Can't search Outlook 365 (Exchange) from Windows Explorer search (or a script using search-ms:query) as I could with Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, exchange

I had some simple AutoHotkey scripts to search Outlook, that took advantage of the fact that Windows Search/Indexing worked in Outlook, even hosted on an Exchange server.  That worked in Outlook 2013. My organization recently upgraded to Outlook 365 (also on Exchange), and now the Windows Explorer search function (or search-ms:query called from a script) doesn't find anything in Outlook.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, I could search the email in my Outlook 365 normally via Windows search, I'm afraid the issue may also be related to windows search, maybe you could try to troubleshoot it via windows troubleshooting tools to check if the issue has any difference.

Comment: Sadly, my in house IT folks locked down my computer so that I can't touch the Indexing parameters.